# Error in running application in android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse

I have created a sample Hello World program in android it was working fine till now. But suddenly I found that my application cannot run in emulator. I have tried with 2.1, 2.2 2.3 emulators. I found the following issue

Please ensure that adb is correctly located at `'C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe'` and can be executed

I have checked in the menationed path adb is present there. Also If I double click that file I can execute the adb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered a similar error. I have no explanation why but I may be able to help you out.

Exit out of eclipse (I assume that's what you're using).

Open task manager.

Go to the **Processes** tab.

Kill the process adb.exe.

Restart eclipse and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I am accepting your answer because it worked for me. But What is the reason behind this?

Comment: I was actually going to post a question asking why it was happening. For some reason (at least on my end) the emulator starts up but DDMS shows nothing in the "devices" field and it has irritated me to no end.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Eclipse? Try to go to Preference an update your sdk location. Click browse and locate it again.

[image]

Comment: it happened to me that for any reason this configuration gets out... when I reconfigured everything started working